# Kile does not find .sty, although command-line pdflatex does

Tags: packages, kile

OS: Ubuntu 12.04.

I've installed *TexLive* from install-tl-20141123 according to http://tug.org/texlive/quickinstall.html

Then I have installed *Kile* with *Ubuntu Software Center*

I've LaTeX file that uses `beramono` package

```
\usepackage[scaled=0.82]{beramono}
```

When I compile my file with command-line `pdflatex`, beramono is used.

But when I use *PDFLaTeX* button in *Kile* editor I get error

`File 'beramono.sty' not found`

Comment: Are you 100% sure that you do not have two different LaTeX installations on your computer? When compiling something in Kile, have a look in the generated `.log` file. The very first line tells us which LaTeX version you have. Try posting that information. A bit further down you will find the location of packages. Try posting one of those as well. Then we can soon see if you have some problems on your computer.

Comment: @daleif I should not be sure. I had TexLive installed from _Ubuntu Software Center_ but I also uninstalled it with _USC_.

Comment: From command-line `pdflatex --version` I get `pdfTeX 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.15 (TeX Live 2014)`. In the Kile log file I have `Version 3.1415926-2.4-1.40.13 (TeX Live 2012/Debian)`. What should I do to fix this mess?

Comment: How exactly did you add the TUG TeX Live 2014 to the system PATH? We are mostly interested in the data from a log file from a Kile compilation, since it seems to be different from a compilation from the command line

Comment: @daleif Command line: `PATH=/usr/local/texlive/2014/bin/x86_64-linux:/usr/lib/lightdm/lightdm:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games`

Comment: But where exactly? which file did you add it to?

Comment: Installing Kile will have installed Ubuntu's TL as a dependency. You should uninstall Ubuntu's TL and install a 'dummy' TL package to convince your package manager that the dependencies for Kile are installed without need for it to install TL again. If you search for 'vanilla', one of the top hits will be a much-viewed question explaining how to do this on Debian and Ubuntu systems, in particular.

Comment: @daleif I did not. Now it is saved in `.profile` file in home directory.

Comment: @cfr, it does not really matter, if the TUG TL path was added to the wrong file, then Kile will not find it anyway.

Comment: @user2793410, if you just added it to `.profile`, did you remember to log out and in again? I just tested that, and then TUG TL 2014 should work, even from Kile (tested on a Ubuntu 14.04)

Comment: @daleif On its own, uninstalling Ubuntu's version will not solve the problem. However, it really would be best to do this. I meant the suggestion as a supplement to your recommendation rather than an alternative. (Your point is correct, as far as I know. That is, I don't have Ubuntu but I'd assume it is sufficiently similar.)

Comment: @user2793410 You did not what? See http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1092/how-to-install-vanilla-texlive-on-debian-or-ubuntu also.

Comment: @daleif After reboot. PATH is remembered. Result is quite surprising. Now command-line pdflatex also does not work since it uses wrong version `pdfTeX, Version 3.1415926-2.4-1.40.13 (TeX Live 2012/Debian)`.

Comment: @cfr My previous answer was for daleif. I am still reading _How to install “vanilla” TeXLive on Debian or Ubuntu?_ topic.

Comment: @user2793410 I realised that. I didn't understand it as an answer to daleif. ('Where did you...? Which file...?' 'I did not.')

Comment: @user2793410. Then we start all over. (1) Did you change anything PATH related in `.bashrc`? (2) Exactly what is listed in `~/.profile` (might be an idea to update your question with that information). (3) In the command line, what does `which latex` say?

Comment: Also: Does `.bash_profile` or `.bash_login` exist? What does `echo $PATH` give?

Comment: BTW: you do not have to reboot for the changes to take effect, just log out. `~/.profile` is read at login.

Comment: @daleif and cfr I am terribly *sorry* for confusing you both. I made a _typing_ mistake in `.profile` file. Now both command-line and Kile are using same _right_ pdflatex (3.14159265-2.6-1.40.15 (TeX Live 2014)). Kile problem solved.

Comment: I got _wrong_ pdflatex as `/usr/bin/pdflatex` and _right_ pdflatex as `/usr/local/texlive/2014/bin/x86_64-linux/pdflatex`. What should I do about the wrong one?

Comment: As @cfr mentions above your could just delete it by deleting all `texlive-` packages in the package manager. But they may appear again if at some popint you choose to install, say, `texstudio`. Ubuntu TeX Live is marked as recommended when installing `texstudio` and thus is installed unless you ask it not to install any recommended stuff.

Comment: @daleif That should not happen if you install the `dummy` package as described in the instructions because the whole point of doing that is to persuade the package manager that those packages are already installed. (I don't use Ubuntu so I can't say. But the package managers I do use do not then install the distro's TL packages, provided things have been configured correctly.)

Comment: @cfr, agreed, but building the dummy package and understanding why it is needed is hard for normal users

Comment: @daleif I think that is why somebody provides a ready-to-use package and somebody else (at least one someone else) wrote a script which does everything needed. Might not be available for all distros, but it should be pretty straightforward for Debian and Ubuntu. [But I haven't tested these myself since I'm not using these distros and had to spin my own.]

Comment: @daleif True story, understanding that dummy-thing is hard for _normal users_. I've chosen _I'll think of it tomorrow_ approach. **Daleif and cfr**, many thanks for your help and time.

Comment: @cfr Should I also ask for writing the answer for this question?